# Applied modifier, closed blender, and i can't unapply it now

Tags: modifiers, subdivision-surface

I was doing a Buran and I decided to use the subdivision surface modifier to make it look nice. I had a perfectly sharp and flat surface, and while applying the same modifier to other thing, it stopped responding and I had to kill the task. When i open it back up, i notice the mess the modifier did, and want to undo it. I can't find a way to undo the spikey mess it did. Help please.

Answer (score 2):

Applied modifiers cannot be undone after closing.

Your only hope is to try and go check the auto-saved files (if you have "auto-save" on) and find one with a date BEFORE you applied the modifier.

[image]

As to why the modifier created a spikey mess, now that's a greater mystery!